# Dot Net Label PaintEvent

Tags: .net, label, drawimage

The problem is demonstated by the following little program:

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
' RaiseEvent
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Label1.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim img As Image
    img = Image.FromFile("f:/myImage.bmp")
    g.DrawImage(img, New Point(0, 0))
End Sub
```

---

The Image is shown in Label1 because the paint event is raised when the Form is launched. But how can I raise a paint event in the btnGo_Click Event??

I tried a lot of possibilities, but nothing worked. A solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Just [Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=netframework-4.8#system-windows-forms-control-invalidate) the Label:

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Label1.Invalidate();
End Sub
```

This will force it to redraw and therefore also fire the `Paint()` event.